# How to configure Spring JavaMailSenderImpl for XMPP protocol

Tags: java, spring, email, jakarta-mail

How can I configure spring `javaMailSender` to use `XMPP` protocol and send mail for host "**`jabber.abc.com`**"?  How can I configure this `javaMailSender` bean in `context.xml`?

Comment: Why don't use Smack (http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack) for this purpose ? Do you really sure that Java Mail supports XMPP ?

Comment: XMPP in Spring Integration (not email): https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/xmpp